# Scalar and Vector Field definitions

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, vector-fields, scalar-fields

I want to ask somethings about scalar and vector fields.

1. Formally is the definition of a scalar field simply a function of the type $$f:V\rightarrow F$$ where V is an arbitrary vector space and F is an arbitrary algebraic field.
2. Formally is the definition of vector field: a vector valued function of the type $$f:V\rightarrow W$$ where V and W are arbitrary vector spaces.
3. If i am right about 1) and 2) then when drawing/visualising vector fields and scalar fields, is it simply a convention to use the domain of the functions as 'points' and the codomain of the function as 'vector arrows' for example: when drawing/plotting the assignment $$(2,3) \mapsto(5,6)$$ we think about this as 'to the point (2,3), we assign a vector arrow (5,6)' however a perfectly different way of thinking about this is to say 'the point(2,3) goes to the point(5,6)'(which would of course be a coordinate transformation) or 'the vector arrow (2,3) goes to the vector arrow(5,6)' these are different interpretations of what means "(2,3) maps to (5,6)" however from an abstract point of view these ways should mean the same thing i.e $$F(2,3)=(5,6)$$ where $$F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$
    
    
   Thank you for any clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the level of abstraction you're working at. At the level of abstraction commonly used in, say, physics,

- a [scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field) is a function $f : X \to K$ where $K = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $X$ in full generality may be an arbitrary set but in practice is a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold). If $X$ is a [smooth manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) then $f$ is often but not always required to be smooth.
- a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) is an assignment, to each point $x \in X$ of a smooth manifold, of a tangent vector $v_x$ in the [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) $T_x(X)$ at $x$. Formally, this is a section of the [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle) $T(X)$. $v_x$ is often but not always required to be smooth. If $X$ is an open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the tangent space at any point can be canonically identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ so we can just work with functions $X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ but in general no such identification is possible globally.

Technically one could imagine calling a function $f : X \to V$ where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space a "vector field" but this would be nonstandard. This corresponds to a section of the [trivial bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_bundle) with fiber $V$ which will differ from the tangent bundle of $X$ in general.

As for your third question, yes, you're technically right, but the point of doing this is to think about a vector field as an object "living on" $X$ in some sense. This is a bit vague but it becomes a lot clearer when considering nontrivial tangent bundles.

Comment: Hmm okai, this is my first year of studying vector calc (year 2 math Phys student) and im not familiar with all those terms yet however, is it okay for me to think of it as scalar fields have domains arbitrary sets and codomain arbitrary scalar fields and vector fields have domain arbitrary sets and codomain vector spaces?

Comment: @Luca: that's fine for scalar fields, and for vector fields that's alright for now but you should be aware that people don't actually use the term "vector field" that way (that I know of). There's a word that should exist here but doesn't.

Comment: Also, my professor answered to 3) my saying that the other two interpretations are misleading and he gave the reason: "Your other way of thinking is misleading, because the domain does not need to be a vector space. That is, we can add two vectors at the same point, but the meaning of F(a+b) is in general not well-defined, while of course F(a) and F(b) are both well-defined. We use the vector structure of the domain where a vector field F is defined only to parametrise the points of this domain (i.e. use vectors that point to a point of interest). " I don't quite understand his point

Comment: @Luca: well, it's true that the domain doesn't need to be a vector space. I think when your professor says "vector structure" they're just talking about using coordinates but I'm not sure, you'd have to ask them.